# zxing camera view for scanning is upside down

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am developing the barcode scanner in Android using Zxing library. Scanner is working as expected but the camera view for scanning is upside down like in the screenshot. How to resolve it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try for camera orientation

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

and declare in manifest like below :

```
<activity
android:name="CaptureActivity"
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

For portrait and landscape orientation add line in `integrator`

```
integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);//"additional property"
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am using Vuzix barcode scanner lib. I am not sure if there is CaptureActivity class in Vuzix which I doubt so.

Answer (score 0):

Set your apps screen orientation to sensorLandscape and not landscape